# Close left-nav using Javascript when I click anywhere on the screen

Tags: javascript, html

in my application I have a left navigation menu. The menu is basically a `<div>` which looks like this -

```
<div id ="pdAppSidenav" style="display:none">
Blah blah blah
</div>
```

As you can see, this menu is not displayed by default. My webpage has an icon and I want that clicking on this icon should open the left navigation menu and re clicking the same icon should close the menu. I also want that when the menu is open, clicking anywhere on the screen should close it.

Please note that the icon is represented as a `<div>` as follows -

```
<div id="hamburgerIconId" class="hamburgerIcon"></div>
```

For this, i have written the following code -

```
function leftnav() {
  var collapse_sidebar = document.getElementById('pdAppSidenav');
  var  collapse_sidebar_icon = document.getElementById("hamburgerIconId");
    var isOpen="false"
        collapse_sidebar_icon.onclick = function() { 
            if(isOpen==="false"){
                collapse_sidebar.style.display = "block";
            collapse_sidebar.style.width = "250px";
                isOpen="true";
                console.log("1");
            }
            else{
                collapse_sidebar.style.display = "none";
            collapse_sidebar.style.width = "0px";
                isOpen  = "false";
                console.log("2");
            }

    }
        window.onclick = function() {
        if (isOpen==="true") {          
            collapse_sidebar.style.display = "none";
            collapse_sidebar.style.width = "0px";
            isOpen="false";
            console.log("3");
        }
        }
```

Now, when I click on the icon, it triggers both the onclick functions associated with the icon and the window which means that `1` and `3` are printed in the console. How do I achieve my desired result?

Comment: I have added an answer for your problem. Please check and let me know by commenting below If you need any help

Comment: @SuvethanNantha - I can't use a button as the clickable area is a div. Could you help?

Comment: I have updated the answer with your div icon as you provided. please check now

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it's correct and accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it with **jquery** as shown in the below code for the demonstration purpose I have used the button instead of the icon.

**Javascript**

```
    var isImageDiv=false;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#hamburgerIconId").click(function () {
        if(isImageDiv)
            leftnav();
        });
    });

    function leftnav() {
        $("#pdAppSidenav").toggle(); 
    }



   $(document).mouseup(function(e) 
   {
         isImageDiv=false;
       var container = $("#pdAppSidenav");
             var imageDiv=$('#hamburgerIconId');
       if (container.is(e.target)) 
       {
           container.hide();
       }
       else if(imageDiv.is(e.target))
       {
                isImageDiv=true;
       }
       else
       {
            container.hide();
       }
   });
```

**HTML**

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="hamburgerIconId" class="hamburgerIcon">Click Me</div>

<div id ="pdAppSidenav" style="display:none;width:250px">
Blah blah blah
</div>
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Suvethan/sLr12hy7/7/)

When you click the div icon it will toggle the div and vice versa. Also when you click outside the div it will hide the div.